# Close stderr pipe of a child process on linux using Qt

Tags: linux, qt, pipe, stderr

I would like to know how to actually close / delete the pipe of a child process started with QProcess on linux.

```
QProcess process;
process.start(QString("/usr/bin/vi"), QStringList());
process.closeReadChannel(QProcess::StandardError);
```

Using the above code, does not result in closing this pipe:

```
Feb 12 12:56 0 -> pipe:[2249624]
Feb 12 12:56 1 -> pipe:[2249625]
Feb 12 12:56 2 -> pipe:[2249626]
```

Is there a way to close the stdErr pipe with Qt?

Regards,
Frogtime

Comment: Probably, it is the `stdout` pipes you can see. You can try to append `process.closeReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);`

Comment: 2 is usualy stderr. And appending your suggestion, doesn't change the output of /proc/<pid>/fd

Comment: You might have to inherit from `QProcess` and override [`QProcess::setupChildProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setupChildProcess).  That would allow you to close file handles explicitly *before* the requested executable is `exec'd`.

Comment: this was a good hint, but sadly calling `::fclose(stderr);` does not do the job.

Comment: You might need to be a bit more forceful: e.g. something like `::close(2)`.

Comment: This didn't work either.